# Select all records from one table and sum from the second table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I can't figure out where the problem is with my MySQL statement. I have a table Estimates and a table Invoices. Each Estimate can have multiple Invoices (for example deposit for the estimate and then the  remaining balance). I am trying to select all Estimates from Estimates and Sum the total of Invoices to each corresponding Estimate. When I run this query, then Estimates with no corresponding Invoice are not included in the final result. I though that LEFT JOIN would select all of them but it seems that Estimates with no corresponding Invoice are not selected. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT p.EstimateID, p.ClientName, p.EstimateTitle, p.EstimateTotalWithTax, SUM(c.InvoiceTotalWithTax)
FROM Estimates p LEFT JOIN
Invoices c ON p.EstimateID = c.EstimateID
WHERE p.EstStatusDateAndTime BETWEEN '2019-1-1  00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
AND (p.EstStatus = 3)
AND p.EstimateActive = 'Active' 
AND (p.Template !='Yes' OR p.Template IS NULL)

AND c.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2019-1-1  00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
AND (c.InvoiceStatus = '1' OR c.InvoiceStatus = '2')
 AND (c.InvoiceActive != 0 OR c.InvoiceActive IS NULL)

GROUP BY p.EstimateID
```

Comment: By using fields of the *left* table in your `WHERE` clause you effectively convert your `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.  You need to remember that in SQL `NULL` is not equal to any value, including another `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move all conditions that relate to the `left join`ed table (the invoice table) to the `on` clause of the `left join`. Otherwise, when an estimate has no invoice, the conditions on invoice columns in the `where` clause cannot be satisfied, and the corresponding estimate is evicted from the result set (basically, the `left join` becomes an `inner join`).

```
SELECT 
    p.EstimateID, 
    p.ClientName, 
    p.EstimateTitle, 
    p.EstimateTotalWithTax, 
    SUM(c.InvoiceTotalWithTax)
FROM Estimates p 
LEFT JOIN Invoices c 
    ON p.EstimateID = c.EstimateID
    AND c.InvoiceDate >= '2019-01-01' 
    AND c.InvoiceDate < '2020-01-01'
    AND c.InvoiceStatus IN (1, 2)
    AND (c.InvoiceActive != 0 OR c.InvoiceActive IS NULL)
WHERE 
    p.EstStatusDateAndTime >= '2019-01-01' 
    AND p.EstStatusDateAndTime < '2020-01-01'
    AND p.EstStatus = 3
    AND p.EstimateActive = 'Active' 
    AND (p.Template !='Yes' OR p.Template IS NULL)
GROUP BY p.EstimateID
```

Other changes to your query:

- `(c.InvoiceStatus = '1' OR c.InvoiceStatus = '2')` can be simplified as a `IN` condition (I would also assume that this column is numeric, so numbers should not be quoted)
- I find that `c.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2019-1-1  00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'` is better written `c.InvoiceDate >= '2019-01-01' AND c.InvoiceDate < '2020-01-01'`
- I also removed a few superfluous parentheses